# MagicEden DutchAuction address

Tags: solana-program, ledger, magiceden, historical-data, pubkey

MagicEden has a few programs, such as `EnglishAuction`, `EnglishAuctionSpl`, `DutchAuction`, and, possibly `DutchAuctionSpl`.
But I weren't able to find address of a `DutchAuction` program anywhere.
What is it?

Reference for other programs:

```
ENGLISH_AUCTION := EA15T2W45BJFm71XmB5VGcsiWGKZTNfnK6aCmE2Hb5eC;
ENGLISH_AUCTION_SPL := EASAq8b2mUQLYZGZqfUyFJgALEu88aEUizFWxtwRYb5R;
```

Comment: How do you know DutchAuction exists?

Comment: > There are two types of auctions for NFTs on Magic Eden: Dutch and English.


https://blog.magiceden.io/intro-to-digital-art-nft-auctions-on-solana

Comment: Maybe they are both on the same smart contract

Comment: They aren't. You can look at IDL used by EnglishAuction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program address is DA14CwvMNkbMggye6Fkvqa1cMxo2Rh3neLvo8ufWoyeL

https://solscan.io/account/DA14CwvMNkbMggye6Fkvqa1cMxo2Rh3neLvo8ufWoyeL

How did i find it? Most auctions on the UI are english auctions, so i failed there. However, opening the english auction program, i thought about scanning what other programs the update authority has.

The update authority is A2sJmQ54Fv3kJuRwhG8KyFTjYNF7o9qgT4MvSEUSMSev

I ran in the solana CLI a search for other programs which have this address as authority

`solana program show --buffer-authority A2sJmQ54Fv3kJuRwhG8KyFTjYNF7o9qgT4MvSEUSMSev --programs -um`

```
Program Id                                   | Slot      | Authority                                    | Balance
EA15T2W45BJFm71XmB5VGcsiWGKZTNfnK6aCmE2Hb5eC | 134983193 | A2sJmQ54Fv3kJuRwhG8KyFTjYNF7o9qgT4MvSEUSMSev | 4.47297624 SOL
CMZYPASGWeTz7RNGHaRJfCq2XQ5pYK6nDvVQxzkH51zb | 158679831 | A2sJmQ54Fv3kJuRwhG8KyFTjYNF7o9qgT4MvSEUSMSev | 7.86945624 SOL
DA14CwvMNkbMggye6Fkvqa1cMxo2Rh3neLvo8ufWoyeL | 126213168 | A2sJmQ54Fv3kJuRwhG8KyFTjYNF7o9qgT4MvSEUSMSev | 5.27176152 SOL
```

DA..., Dutch auction, like the IDL also confirms

Comment: The saddest thing in the end is that they do not used this auction and it has only 10-15 calls into it. Thank you!